# Create a pivot table by joining two tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two tables, each on its own worksheet, that are linked to Sharepoint lists, where one   table has a foreign key that maps to the other's primary key. E.g.:

```
sheet: flavors
+----+------------+------+
| ID |   Flavor   | kCal |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 | chocolate  |   45 |
|  2 | vanilla    |   20 |
|  3 | strawberry |   38 |
+----+------------+------+

sheet: orders
+----+----------+
| ID | flavorID |
+----+----------+
|  1 |       1  |
|  2 |       3  |
|  3 |       2  |
|  4 |       1  |
|  5 |       3  |
+----+----------+
```

I'd like to join these tables on a third sheet.  Because these are linked tables, the size of each table will vary over time.  I know that `flavors` has a one-to-many relationship with `orders`, so I thought about having putting a formulas so that:

- column A=orders.ID
- column B=vlookup of flavors.Flavor
- column C=vlookup of flavors.kCal

But that would require putting ~3 million formulas on the join sheet, and I'd rather not have to run all those calculations if I only have a couple rows in each list.  Is there a way to set up the join table so that it's updated when I refresh the data, but not slowed down by a massive number of excess calculations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerPivot, a free download for Excel 2010 to create that scenario with joined tables.

Download link for the add-in (make sure you get the 2010 version) http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel/download-powerpivot-HA101959985.aspx

Creating a lookup relationship between two tables is described here: 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel/download-powerpivot-HA101959985.aspx